# How to programmatically create textbox based on mvc view model object?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, textbox, data-annotations

Is there a way to programmatically create a textbox based on a view model object?  Let me elaborate.  Take for example, a standard ViewModel object like password.

```
public class PassWordViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Now take for example, a textbox control built programmatically:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
textBox.MaxLength = 10;
```

How do I programmatically create a textbox which contains all of the properties that are set on my model object?

```
TextBox textBox = [CREATE TEXTBOX FROM MY PASSWORD 
VIEWMODEL OBJECT CONTAINING ALL THE DATA ANNOTATED 
PROPERTIES]
```

Comment: Unsure what you're asking. You've _already_ set the properties programmatically (aka via the annotations). Are you asking how to _render_ - e.g. `@Html.PasswordFor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unusual to have to do this, but it's possible all the same.

You first need to create an instance of `HtmlHelper<PasswordViewModel>` in your controller:

```
var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, new NullObjectView(), ViewData, TempData, TextWriter.Null);
var helper = new HtmlHelper<PassWordViewModel>(viewContext, new ViewPage());
```

As you can see, there is a `NullObjectView` class in there, which is as follows:

```
public class NullObjectView : IView
{
    public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
    {

    }
}
```

Then create the textbox using `System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor()`:

```
var textbox = InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(helper, x => x.Password);
```

This returns an `MvcHtmlString`, which will contain the full textbox output of:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field Password must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '10'." data-val-maxlength-max="10" id="Password" name="Password" value="" type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks, this is going to help a lot for the odd scenario I find myself in!  Your solution works very well!  Thank you for taking the time to help out.